# Git: when I revert I get some error code that bug the app

Tags: git

I was working on an android app, 2 day later I was trying to revert to a previous commit that I publish. And baaam :

I find a strange code in all activity and bugging the app

The question is WHY ? and how that happen ? is that normal ?

```
           <Button
+          android:id="@+id/add2"
+          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
+          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
+          android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/add1"
+          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add1"
+          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
+=======    <<<== this is the added code
+      <Button
           android:id="@+id/add1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
           android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
+>>>>>>> 06ffa5de32253deb4076440e1f23e136a8536015    <<<== this is the added code
           android:background="#8258FA"
           android:text="Read" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, there really isn't enough information to help you.  What, even, is your question?

Comment: the question is WHY ? and how that happen ? is that normal ?

Comment: you seem to be in the middle of a conflict. resolve it. check here http://git-scm.com/documentation

Comment: This is not programming related, but is rather a git related question.

Comment: I'm just asking if that happend ofen ? or i just did a bad manip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two possibilities:

- Someone in your team has commits a file which contains conflicts markup and might fix this mistake in a commit just after
- You're yourself in conflict with your current edits and you need to fix them by chosing which part of the file you want to keep

To respond at your comment, conflicts can appear often when severals developpers are working on the same file, because people may change the same lines but with differents modifications so the VCS (git here) doesn't know which is the more legit modification.

Comment: yes! you right. Because when tryed to revert from the GitHub app , it tells me that i should fix a conflict ...

Comment: Is my first post in the site so ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Back and with a solution :D

when we are in conflict , i mean :
Is when you change somthing (file, line, ..) with a "**branche1**" , and change the same thing withe other branche "**branche2**" or by other **user**. Mr git to make sure that everything is good and no one is going to lose his work, he turne to a stat called "Conflict" in order to save only one and correct version of (file,line). this stat turn on when you try to merge.

solution :

1-check the file that is in conflict, generaly when you try to merge it mention which file is      in conflict .
2- open the file , so you gonna find (in my case) :

```
<<<<<<< HEAD    //start of version 1  
        add2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        read = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 =======   // end of virsion1

>>>>>>> kikaandBr1  //start of version 2
        readd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);



        add2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 =======  // end of version 2
```

<<<<<

3- when you delect the wrong/old version, you should tell to git that you modified the conflict by :
$ git add \

then you can merge without problems :D